# Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, create-table

When i try to create a table called Sales, MySQL gives the following error. I can't tell what the problem is, and I glanced at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html to see what mistake i made, but I can't tell. 
I get this error in MySQL 5.6.11, but not in 5.1.67

```
Error
SQL query:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Sales(

name VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
address VARCHAR( 70 ) NOT NULL ,
serialsold VARCHAR( 20 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL ,
background_check VARCHAR( 9 ) NOT NULL ,
soldfor FLOAT NOT NULL ,
datesold TIMESTAMP DEFAULTNOW( ) ,
FOREIGN KEY ( serialsold ) REFERENCES Guns( serialnumber ) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE ,
PRIMARY KEY ( background_check )
);

MySQL said: Documentation

#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

my Guns and Purchases Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Purchases
(
    name          VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    address       VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    serialbought  VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    boughtfor     FLOAT,
    datebought    TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW(),
    PRIMARY KEY (serialbought)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Guns
( 
  sequence      INTEGER(4)  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  manufacturer  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  model         VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  caliber       VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  serialnumber  VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  type          VARCHAR(10) NOT NULl,
  sellsfor      FLOAT DEFAULT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (serialnumber) REFERENCES Purchases(serialbought)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT,
  PRIMARY KEY (sequence)
);
```

Comment: Please show your `Guns` table

Comment: One of the reason could be the series in which you are creating the tables *(creating children before parents)* set `foreign_key_checks=0` at the starting of your DDL script.So the order by creation doesn't create problem.

Comment: I tried that already, it didn't work. I created purchases first, then guns, then tried sales and it didn't work.

Comment: SerialSold has to be unique, so you can never sell the same gun twice in the lifetime of your application? This might be desired functionality, but I can think of scenario's where you end up with unsellable items because your software doesn't allow selling it... If I buy a gun, sell it back to you, you can't sell it anymore.

Answer (score 9):

You defined a field `serialsold` as not-nullable -

```
serialsold VARCHAR( 20 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL
```

but then you are trying to add action with SET NULL clause -

```
ON DELETE SET NULL
```

Change one of these options and try to create table.